# PHP, html код в бд или в файлах?

Tags: php, html, mysql, база-данных, веб-программирование

Мне нужно было хранить *html* код в *базе данных*, но мне показалось, что лучше в *базе данных* хранить только ссылку на новый *html* файл, в котором *html код*.

Все правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Смотря чего хочется добиться.

При первом варианте время и ресурсы тратятся только на то, чтобы получить код из базы данных. Но в этом случае редактирование кода вручную заметно труднее.

Во втором случае время тратится не только на получение ссылки из БД, но и на считывание файла с жесткого диска. Зато html-страницу как отдельный файл редактировать конечно легче.

Все как всегда зависит от поставленных целей и наличия сопутствующих ресурсов.